# Not a valid ObjectId PyMango

Tags: python, discord.py, pymongo

I am using PyMongo as database for my discord bot.
I am making a blacklisting system where the bot doesn't run the commands given by the blacklisted users.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    author_id = message.author.id
    id = str(author_id) 
    objInstance = ObjectId(id)
    collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if True:
        await message.channel.send("You have been blacklisted from using the bot commands")
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(aliases=["bl"])
async def blacklist(ctx, * ,member: discord.Member):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("Mention a member to blacklist them!")
    else:
        post = {"_id": member.id}
        collection.insert_one(post)
```

I am getting this error:

```
line 38, in _raise_invalid_id
    raise InvalidId(
bson.errors.InvalidId: '851756211841925141' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a
24-character hex string
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, when using `ObjectId()` the parameter must match a format aligned with MongoDB's ObjectId type.

Maybe you meant to do:

```
collection.find_one({"_id": id})
```

see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

As a side note avoid `id` as a variable name as `id` is a built-in function.